# Trigger method on keypress

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm struggling to trigger a function  on keypress.

Of course Angular have  docs for this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress

the problem is that when I pass a function inside of the directive it doesnt' get called.

for example:

it works:

```
<input ng-keypress="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">
key press count: {{count}}
```

but it doesn't:

```
<input ng-keypress="someFunction()">

//function inside  the controller
function someFunction(){
  console.log("Hey there");
}
```

**EDIT: CORRECT (BUT FAKE) METHOD**

```
$scope.someFunction = function(){
  console.log("Hey there");
}
```

I saw some similar question but none of them had an example using functions.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Did you add the function to the scope?

Comment: Should probably be `$scope.someFunction = function() {`

Comment: Sorry Kevin B, yes I did put the method in scope I'll edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-keypress` example usage: 
view:

```
<div ng-app='App' ng-controller="AppCtrl">

<!-- if you are trying to figure out which key was pressed: -->
<input ng-keypress="someFunction($event)">   
<p> key value: {{keyWasThis}} </p>

<!-- if you just want to know if any key was pressed: -->
<input ng-keypress="someOtherFunction()">   
<p> event: {{pressed}} </p>
```

js:

```
angular.module('App', [])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.someFunction = function(event) {    // function 
      $scope.keyWasThis = event.which;
     }; 

    $scope.someOtherFunction = function() {    // function 
      $scope.pressed = "yes";
     };

});
```

working example using `ng-keypress` : https://jsfiddle.net/tbsxe80e/1/

alternatives, angularjs docs: [ng-keydown](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeydown), [ng-keyup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup)